# find string in list of pandas dataframe by part of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to find element in each column list based on part of element. `a1` should find by `a` value.
`contains` work if `column1` is a single string and in case of list in `column1` not work

Original Data Frame:

[image]

Desire result:

[image]

here is the code i tried:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : [['a-1','b-1','c-1'], ['a-2','b-2','c-2'], ['a-3','b-3','c-3']]})
frame['column1']=frame[frame['column1'].str.contains('a')]
```

Comment: `frame['col1'] = [[a for a in x if 'a' in a] for x in frame['col1']`?

Comment: thanks @QuangHoang, how can i have it as single string `a-1` not `[a-1]`

Comment: `s = frame['col1'].explode(); s[s.str.startswith('a')]`...

Comment: Same thing, one-line because `loc` can accept a callable `frame['column1'].explode().loc[lambda x: x.str.contains('a')]`

Comment: @QuangHoang it's work thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the list doesn't change, you can try something like

```
frame['column1'] = frame['column1'].str[0]

frame
```

**Output**

```
   column1
0   a-1
1   a-2
2   a-3
```